# How can i compare my 2 SQL tables?

Tags: sql, compare

I have 2 tables, with a bunch of supplier ports in them, some more fields than in the 2 screenshots but the important fields are the 3 here, supplier no, port code and port active.

I would like to compare there 2 tables in 3 different ways:

1. What does table 1 have, that table 2 does not have?
2. What does table 2 have, that table 1 does not have?
3. What do both tables have, but they are different, eg: port active = Y or table 1 and N in the same port in table 2.

What would be the best way to go about comparing them like this?

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Comment: Put your actually question here instead of paste a link here.

Comment: Except and intersect should help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a starting tip, most people here want formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempts. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What is the primary key of those tables? Or which columns can be used to match rows in one table to the rows of the other table?

Answer (score 0):

If `SUPPLIER_NO` can be considered a primary key or at least unique the following query, will return what is available in `Table1` that is not available in `Table2`

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B
  ON A.SUPPLIER_NO = B.SUPPLIER_NO
WHERE B.SUPPLIER_NO IS NULL
```

Just switch `Table1` and `Table2` to get what is available in `Table2` and not in `Table1`.

To get differences between tables you can use set operators but you should convert the last field value so that it has the same domain in both tables (e.g. `PORT_ACTIVE` in `Table2` should be valued with `'Y'` and `'N'` instead of `true` and `false`). For example, we may consider this table `Table2_Converted`.
Then you can perform a `MINUS` or `EXCEPT` (it can be different based on the RDBMS you are using) operation between the two tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T1.* FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2_Converted T2 ON T1.SUPPLIER_NO=T2.SUPPLIER_NO)
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T2.* FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2_Converted T2 ON T1.SUPPLIER_NO=T2.SUPPLIER_NO)
```

will return everything available in both tables but that is different in `Table1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T2.* FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2_Converted T2 ON T1.SUPPLIER_NO=T2.SUPPLIER_NO)
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T1.* FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2_Converted T2 ON T1.SUPPLIER_NO=T2.SUPPLIER_NO)
```

Just switch the two statements to have everything available in both tables, but that is different in `Table2`.

Comment: Note that `MINUS` is non-standard SQL. It's Oracle's "version" of the standard `EXCEPT` operator

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what [*folco*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9405427/folco) already said, you can also use the **NOT IN** operator in the **WHERE** clause.

I'm going to consider **SUPPLIER_NO** as **PRIMARY KEY** in the next examples :

```
SELECT *
    -> FROM Supplier
    -> WHERE Supplier_No NOT IN(
    -> SELECT Supplier_No
    -> FROM Supplier2);
```

Here is the output

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+
|    | Supplier_No | Port_Code | Active |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+
|  6 |         996 | CAN       | Y      |
|  7 |         996 | HKG       | Y      |
|  8 |         996 | SHA       | Y      |
|  9 |         996 | SHK       | Y      |
| 10 |         996 | TAO       | Y      |
| 11 |         996 | XMN       | Y      |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

And vice versa to obtain the other informations you want :

```
SELECT *
    -> FROM Supplier2
    -> WHERE Supplier_No NOT IN(
    -> SELECT Supplier_No
    -> FROM Supplier);
```

Output :

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|    | Supplier_No | Port_Code | Port_Active |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |        1384 | YTN       | false       |
|  2 |        1543 | SHA       | true        |
|  3 |        1982 | SHA       | true        |
|  4 |        1662 | SHA       | true        |
|  5 |        1384 | SHA       | true        |
|  6 |        1543 | TAO       | true        |
|  8 |        1982 | TAO       | true        |
|  9 |        1662 | TAO       | true        |
| 10 |        1678 | SWA       | true        |
| 12 |        1991 | SWA       | true        |
| 13 |        1543 | XMN       | true        |
| 14 |        1982 | XMN       | true        |
| 15 |        1991 | CWN       | false       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```